# Auto list member in xaml + visual studio 2012

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012

In my xaml file I can't use ctrl+space and don't show me auto list member!! I check the tools>options>text editor>xaml>general but "Auto list members" is hidden and I can't change the status. but my c# language "auto list members" work and I can change..
Do you have any Idea for xaml...?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Blow options should be enabled:

Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->General->Auto list members
Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->General->Parameter information
Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Intellisense->Show completion list after a character is typed

If it doesn't work try this: Tools->Import and export settings->Reset all settings

Comment: Thanks Yoselin Medina, however, I said that C# file works but xaml file doesn't work, it parameter setting in texteditor is hidden for xaml. and I have another question? If I reset all setting, many change can be occur in my environment?

Comment: Hi Sonia, apparently Auto list member in xaml + visual studio 2012 it is a common bug that has been fixed in : Visual Studio 2012 Update 2...link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2797912#fixedissues

Comment: Hi Sonia, glad to hear it..Finally Microsoft fixed the bug, now XAML IntelliSense should support filtered List Members, just like C# IntelliSense in VS2012 Update 2...Regards

Answer (score 1):

```
Tools->Import and export settings->Import selected environment settings->yes or no (I use no)->Visual C#
```

Just select XAML and XAML text editor in  all `settings|Options|Test Editor`.

Comment: This fixed my VS 2015 and not showing completion list after character is typed. Thnx.